# Private Blockchain VS regular Public-key cryptography

Tags: cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, blockchain

Private Blockchain (permissioned) VS regular Public-key cryptography: What is the need and add-value of a private blockchain  (permissioned) if one can use normal regular public-key cryptography?

Comment: Can you include in which context you are comparing these?

Comment: Hi and welcome on Information Security. You question would benefit, if it showed resources you already have consulted. The comparison also seems to be a bit odd, since Blockchain (at least as used with all those virtual currencies) uses public-key cryptograpy, it can not be taken away.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this with, I'm in no way an expert on blockchain.

Currently there's two types of blockchain in the Crypto Currency world. Private ledger and public ledger.

A public ledger allows everyone on the network to validate how many coins someone has and it is the foundation of the zero trust system. You don't need to trust that I sent you coins because you can look at the public ledger and validate it for yourself. This is why there's often a long delay when sending coins to a business because they require a few blocks to be added to the ledger before they agree a transaction has taken place.

Private ledgers on the other hand hide transactions. Depending on the implementation, if you wanted to prove a transaction has taken place, you need to either find a trusted 3rd party that has access to the ledger or some other implementation. In the case of Monero, they have a transaction key that can be retrieved by the sender and used to validate a transaction by the receiver.

That's just the world of crypto currency. There's obviously an infinite amount of uses for blockchain technology. One such example would be healthcare records. This is an excellent example of something that we want to track over our life but also don't want public. It would be a great test case for a private ledger blockchain.

On the other hand there's things like property sale records. These are something that should be tracked and each transfer public and immutable. Another great test case for a public blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, public-key/asymmetric-key cryptography is very briefly speaking, the idea of utilizing the concepts of a public and private key for the purposes of encryption and decryption, respectively. Blockchain technology is just a concept that uses this idea. Obviously, this is a very basic overview and the details of each of these two concepts take entire books/courses to fully explain. But to clear up your overall perception on how these two concepts interrelate, think of it this way:

Think of the concept of a lock ( I mean the physical version, some metal piece of work with a keyhole in its center ). Now this concept is used by the doors of your house, your automobile doors, treasure chests, ...etc,. Now you wouldn't say, "why would I use a treasure chest, when I can just use a lock ? ". The chest merely utilizes the concept of the lock. The chest's functionality can't really be compared to that of the lock, the chest is used to store valuable items, but needs the lock to do it effectively. Whereas the lock is a lock regardless of whether the chest is using it.